# React js update form value using useState

Tags: reactjs

I have a React functional component, a form accepting information for events. I need to send the filled in form info using a POST request. My formData state is not updating, I have tried different onChange functions to try and get this to work. Any ideas where I am going wrong?

`

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

import axios from 'axios';

import Input from './Input';

import react, {useState, useEffect} from "react";

import DateTimePicker from 'react-datetime-picker';

import TimePicker from "react-time-picker";

import DatePicker from "react-date-picker";

const url = 'http://localhost:5000/events/create'

const EventForm = (props)=> {
const [dateValue, onChangeDate] = useState(new Date());

const [timeValue, onChangeTime] = useState();

const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    contactEmail: '',
    eventTitle: '',
    eventDescription: '', 
})

function onChange (e) {
    let name = e.target.name ;
    let value = e.target.value;
    let formObj = { ...formData };
    setFormData({ ...formData, [name]: value });
    console.log(formData)
}
const body = {
    firstName: formData.firstName,
    lastName: formData.lastName,
    contactEmail: formData.contactEmail,
    eventTitle: formData.eventTitle,
    eventDescription: formData.eventDescription,
    eventDate: dateValue,
    eventTime: timeValue,
}
const postFormData = async (e) => {
    console.log(formData)
    e.preventDefault()
    await axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: url,
        data: body,
     })
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(`Error: ${error}`));
}

// const postFormData = async (e) => {
//     e.preventDefault()
//     let newEvent = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/events/create",
//         {
//             method: "POST",
//             headers: {
//                 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
//                 'Accept': 'application/json'
//             },
//             body: JSON.stringify(body)
//         });
//         newEvent = await newEvent.json();
//         console.log(newEvent);
// }
    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
        console.log(formData.firstName)
        }
    })

  return (
    <form onSubmit={props.onSubmit}>
    <>
    {/* <DateTimePicker onChange={onChange} value={value} minDate={new Date()}/> */}
    <StyledForm onSubmit={postFormData}>
        <label>
            First Name
        </label>
        <Input 
            name={"firstName"} 
            placeholder={"First Name"} 
            type={"text"}
            value={formData.firstName}
            onChange={(e) => setFormData({ ...formData, firstName: e.target.value})}
        />
        <label>
            Last Name
        </label>
        <Input 
            name={"lastName"} 
            placeholder={"Last Name"} 
            type={"text"}
            onChange={onChange}
        />
        <label>
            Contact Email
        </label>
        <Input 
            name={"contactEmail"} 
            placeholder={"Email"} 
            type={"email"} 
            onChange={onChange}
        />
        <label>
            Event Date
        </label>
        <DatePicker onChange={onChangeDate} value={dateValue}/>
        <label>
            Event Time
        </label>
        <TimePicker onChange={onChangeTime} value={timeValue} />
        <label>
            Event Description
        </label>
        <Input 
            name={"eventTitle"} 
            placeholder={"Event Title"} 
            type={"text"}
            onChange={onChange}
        />
        <label>
            Event Description
        </label>
        <Input 
            name={"eventDescription"} 
            placeholder={"Event Description"} 
            type={"text"}
            width={"300px"}
            height={"300px"}
            onChange={onChange}
        />


        <Input 
            name={"submit"} 
            type={"submit"} 
            value={"Create"} 
        />       
    </form>
    </>
  );
```

}

export default EventForm;`

Answer (score 1):

The `formData` state variable will not update immediately, your `console.log` will always print the original value *before* the update. Also when the next state is computed using the previous state like in your example, you should use the [functional update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) version of `setState`:

```js
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    contactEmail: '',
    eventTitle: '',
    eventDescription: '', 
})

function onChange (e) {
    let name = e.target.name;
    let value = e.target.value;
    setFormData((currentFormData) => {
      const nextFormData = {
        ...currentFormData,
        [name]: value,
      })
      console.log(nextFormData)
      return nextFormData;
    );
}
```